# JavaFx Webview memory leak on events

Tags: java, javafx, memory-leaks, webview

We're currently developing an application which hugely relies on the JavaFx webview. The layout is loaded by the FXMLLoader and contains a webview with several events like OnScroll, OnMousePressed and OnMouseReleased.

After closing the stage which contains this layout, the stage is properly released from memory, but the controller class stays. I investigated this issue with the help of VisualVM.

Each time I open and close a stage, a new controller class gets loaded into memory and remains there.

In the screenshot below you can see the nearest GC root to my controller class. Highlighted is the OnScroll event of my webview. If i were to remove this event, the next event (OnMouseReleased) would take it's place in this trace.
[image: Webview event leak]

We're using java version jdk1.8.0_65 and JavaFx version 8.0.65-b17.

I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, or if its a bug in JavaFx. However, this is a show stopper for us and any help is greatly appreciated.

Best of wishes,
Mazen

Answer (score 0):

I found it.

The problem weren't webview events. The problem wasn't even the webview itself.
Upon further investigation I found out that the whole scene with every component on it was still in memory.

The problem is the ProgressIndicator I have in my layout. If it is set to an indeterminate state it prevents the scene from getting garbage collected. Resetting the progress to 0 (and therefore making it determinate) prior to closing the stage solved my problem.

Comment: Perhaps you ran across bug [JDK-8094829 Memory leak in JavaFX ProgressIndicator](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8094829). Though that was fixed in Java 8u60 and you are using 8u65, so that would be weird if something similar is recurring.  You may wish to file a [bug report](http://bugreport.java.com).